# How to iterate through all HTML tags in a page using the Agility Pack in C#?

Tags: c#, html, linq, iterator, html-agility-pack

I would like to parse my HTML page in a as generic way as possible. I don't want to build a parser every time the page has been changed so I would like to parse it smartly by the value of the tags.

I know that the HTML Agility Pack provides tools to read and search by the type of tag(td,strong,li etc), but I would like to iterate all the tags and find information which I know by the *content* of the tag and not by the type of the tag because the type can change.

Example:
The page:

```
<table>
<tr valign="top">
<td valign="top">Sex:<br />
</td><td valign="top">Male<br />
</td></tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td valign="top">Current City:<br />
</td><td valign="top">New York<br /></td>
```

- I know that the value will be "Sex:" and the next tag will contain
  the gender.
- I know that the value will be "Current City:" and then    the next
  tag will be the city.

I know I can iterate by the tags  and  but if the tags change my parser will no longer work.

Can I iterate by values and not by the type of tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could input all the nodes inside `<table>` into a `HtmlNodeCollection`. Then iterate through that list of nodes:

`foreach (HtmlNode node in ListofNodes)`

Within that, you could check the `InnerHtml` of each node to check for your specific strings? I guess the table has the same fields each time. Either that, or add id's/css class and look for that specific id/css class.